# Show DIVs that are not empty

Tags: jquery

I have a list of DIVs on a page that contains photo descriptions. They all start with the same id. With the following script I can show them all on the page. However some DIVs can be empty so I want to show only those that contain a text. How can I do that?

```
$('[id^="photoCaption"]').show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use combination of [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector.

```
$('[id^="photoCaption"]:not(:empty)').show();
```

Thanks @guest271314 for [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jenkec4f/)

Comment: Must have posted same piece at same moment :) stacksnippets had error , created jsfiddle

Comment: @guest271314, Yes we posted almost at same time

Comment: You first ! by 19 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('[id^="photoCaption"]')each(function(){
    if($(this).text()) != '') {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't use a single ID more than once on a page. You can however use class.

So you can use

```
if ($(".photocaption").html(""))
{
return false;
} else {
$(this).show();
}
```

Comment: Each ID is different (photoCaption1, photoCaption2, photoCaption3...) but they all start with the same first part which is photoCaption....